# convert svg animation properties in css animation properties

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have SVG opacity animation properties:

```
<animate id="animation1"
        attributeName="opacity"
        from="1"
        to="0"
        dur="1s"
        begin="0.5s;animation2.end" />

    <animate id="animation2"
        attributeName="opacity"
        from="0"
        to="1"
        dur="2s" 
        begin="animation1.end" />
```

i need same properties in css3 i tried:

```
        .opacity-animation{
            -webkit-animation-name: flickerAnimation;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
        }
        @keyframes flickerAnimation {
          0%   { opacity:1; }
          50%  { opacity:0; }
          100% { opacity:1; }
        }
        @-o-keyframes flickerAnimation{
          0%   { opacity:1; }
          50%  { opacity:0; }
          100% { opacity:1; }
        }
        @-moz-keyframes flickerAnimation{
          0%   { opacity:1; }
          50%  { opacity:0; }
          100% { opacity:1; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes flickerAnimation{
          0%   { opacity:1; }
          50%  { opacity:0; }
          100% { opacity:1; }
        }
```

but its not workin with same as svg animation. css3 code opacity loop working quickly.
also see video how its working now. [Video Link](https://share.nexshot.io/DOdgA6Da)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- duration of the first SMIL animation: 1s
- duration of the second SMIL animation: 2s
- makes a total of 3s for the loop, 33% for the first part, 67% for the second.

In addition, the SMil standard for interpolation is `linear`, not some easing.

```
opacity-animation{
        animation-name: flickerAnimation;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes flickerAnimation {
    0%   { opacity:1; }
    33%  { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```